# Azure Synapse Pipeline - Cannot bulk load Az Data-lake files into an Synapse Pool DB Table - Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: azure-storage, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline

I have a Synapse Managed VNet and Synapse Pipelines that interact with an Azure Datalake storage account and Synapse SQL Pool databases.

Within Synapse there is an Synapse Managed Private-End-Point to the datalake that is approved.

The Synapse identity has RBAC 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' on the Storage Account.

When trying to execute the following in the Pipeline..

```
COPY INTO [RawStaged].[Audit_PatientAudit_E8EBCE80]
FROM 'https://storageaccountXXX.blob.core.windows.net/versioner/inbox/landing/abcdef/XXXX-E619-40CA-B45F-9C3AC0328143/20221122105610/bulk_75686_Audit_PatientAudit_20221122105610_ABCDEF-GGGH-44E8-95C5-75D70EA9A45DF.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2);
```

**Error Message**

> Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Cannot bulk load
> because the file
> https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/XXXX/inbox/landing/PrimaryXXXX/abc/abcdef/20221122105610/bulk_75686_Audit_PatientAudit_20221122105610_ABCDEF-GGGH-44E8-95C5-75D70EA9A45DF.csv
> could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

I have looked at the following but these don't resolve my issue...

[Azure blob to Azure SQL Database: Cannot bulk load because the file "xxxx.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835887/azure-blob-to-azure-sql-database-cannot-bulk-load-because-the-file-xxxx-csv-c)

[403 Forbidden when accessing Storage Account through firewall from Azure Synapse's dedicated SQL pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74627750/403-forbidden-when-accessing-storage-account-through-firewall-from-azure-synapse)

I am thinking do I need to give the 'Synapse' managed identity roles/permissions within the 'sql server pool database' the files are being loaded in to ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=managed-identity

[Not able to access data lake file in Azure synapse dedicated pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77457651/not-able-to-access-data-lake-file-in-azure-synapse-dedicated-pool)

Any idea on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had to add '(IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity')' then the Synapse pipleline worked...

COPY INTO [RawStaged].[Audit_PatientAudit_E8EBCE80-E619-40CA-B45F-9C3AC0328143]
FROM 'https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/versioner/inbox/landing/abc/abc-E619-40CA-defg-9C3AC0328143/20221122105610/bulk_75686_.csv'
**WITH (CREDENTIAL = (IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity'), FIRSTROW = 2);**